# phonegap/cordova throws error when building for android after android SDK upgrade

Tags: android, cordova

I updated (through android studio) the android SDK and since then I cannot build an android APK anymore for my phonegap projects.
I also updated phonegap to the latest version (6.4.6) available through NPM.

The (misleading) error thrown is:

```
Error: CordovaError: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
 at <my project dir>/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:45:27
<snip>
```

I checked and ANDROID_HOME is set correctly though.

I checked out the check_reqs.js file referenced in the error above and on the line indicated there is a function that runs a command and throws an error if the command has an error.

The command that triggers the error is this:

```
android list targets --compact
```

Which when run by hand says this:

```
The android command is no longer available.
For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
```

Which leads me to believe that this is a new change in the new android SDK that phonegap/cordova does not manage (yet).

How do I get phonegap to build my project with this new SDK?